# "This row already belongs to this table"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I've read existing code in stackoverflow but I'm still lost as how do I fix this.
This row already belongs to this table.
Any suggestions always is appreciated.
It errors out on my command button save event.
I've listed code for the entire form just to give you an idea on what I'm doing. Hope this helps

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
    Dim con As SqlConnection = CompDB.GetConnection
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim SPgetStandards As String = "dbo.SPgetStandards"
    Dim SPgetRecordDetail As String = "dbo.SPgetRecordDetail"


    Dim dsStandard As New DataSet

    Dim dsRecords As New DataSet
    Dim currentrow As DataRow
    Dim currentcolumn As DataColumn


    MsgBox("Record id is " & RecordID)
    Using con
        con.Open()

        Dim Standardsdataadapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SPgetStandards, con)

        Dim Detaildataadapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SPgetRecordDetail, con)
        Detaildataadapter.Fill(dsRecords, "Record")
        Standardsdataadapter.Fill(dsStandard, "Standard")




        '5/31/13 
        'Figured out how to run a loop through a table and write to the console

        For Each currentrow In dsStandard.Tables("Standard").Rows
            For Each currentcolumn In dsStandard.Tables("Standard").Columns
                'Debug.WriteLine(currentrow(currentcolumn) & ControlChars.Tab & ControlChars.Tab)
                'MsgBox(currentcolumn.ToString)
                'Debug.WriteLine(currentrow.Item(0))
            Next currentcolumn

        Next currentrow

        ' con.Close()
        'con.Dispose()

        Dim newrow As DataRow = dsRecords.Tables("Record").NewRow
        For Each oRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If Convert.ToInt16(oRow.Cells("chkbox").Value) = 1 Then
                ' Debug.WriteLine("It was clicked ", DataGridView1.Columns.Item(1))
                Debug.WriteLine(oRow.Cells("ID").Value)
                'dsStandard.Tables.Add.Rows("RecordID") = 1234
                'dsRecords.Tables.Add.Rows("Standard_Name_ID") = 1234
                ' newrow("Record_Detail_ID") = RecordID
                '  newrow("Record_ID") = RecordID
                newrow("Standard_Name_ID") = (oRow.Cells("ID").Value)
 '/////Errors out here!!!!!dsRecords.Tables("Record").Rows.Add(newrow) '/////Errors out here!!!!!
                dsRecords.AcceptChanges()


            End If

        Next
    End Using




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```
Dim newrow As DataRow = dsRecords.Tables("Record").NewRow
```

To be the first line inside of your `If` block.

Comment: That actually helped no errors but, I have nothing in my database table. So, I have something else incorrect.